huge number of accesses to my server from IPs belonging to Microsoft
For some time now, a large number of accesses to my server from different IPs have been occurring several times a day, each time for 2 to 4 minutes with accesses of between 3 and 10 per second.
All these accesses come from ASN: AS8075 MICROSOFT-CORP-MSN-AS-BLOCK
Does anyone have any idea what this might be?
And who do I contact to find out where these accesses come from?

I -believe- that's the Bing crawler, or at least could be.  Do you have a web site running on that server?  Can you post a couple of the IP's it's coming from?  Or you can check if the IP is a legitimate Bing Bot here https://www.bing.com/toolbox/verify-bingbot

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/278988/massive-increase-in-phony-access-attempts-from-microsoft-ips-what-kind-of-atta

Although a duplicate, this information security question literally asks the exact same thing, about why their server is having a “Massive Increase in Phony Access Attempts from Microsoft IPs”.
And as it turns out, this is just

the "background radiation" of the Internet. This isn't an attack. It's a scan. It's not new. It's been around for a couple decades.

To quote Schroeder’s comment.
So unless it is the Bing crawler, it definitely isn’t Microsoft(!), but it’s nothing to worry about, either.

I'm not sure that Microsoft has nothing to do with this problem. It's their responsibility to check that there's nothing objectionable on their servers. It's a bit easy to say ‘there's nothing we can do’, it's like letting drivers do whatever they want on the roads.

@Chrigou that’s exactly what I’m saying, too. It’s a scan using “Microsoft’s” IPs. It’s also nothing to worry about.
